# How to separate dictionary in data frame each in one column and only keep the value without the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data frame contains columns of dictionaries has few items inside it, i wanat seperate each value in one column and keep only the value.

right now like this

| dic |
| --- |
| {'_id': '1', 'value': 'apple'} |
| {'_id': '2', 'value': 'car'} |

I want them to be like this

| first value | second value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | car |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `pandas.Series` on that column:

```py
>>> df = df['dic'].apply(pd.Series)
>>> df
  _id  value
0   1  apple
1   2    car
```

Then change the column names if needed:

```py
>>> df.columns = ['first value', 'second value']
>>> df
  first value second value
0           1        apple
1           2          car
```

Or, you can just pass the same index with a `lambda` function:

```py
>>> df['dic'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.values(), ['first value', 'second value']))
  first value second value
0           1        apple
1           2          car
```